# how to fetch local phone contacts effeciently

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am using the below code to fetch the local phone contacts. It is working fine and also fetching the contacts very fast.

But the problem comes here, in my contact list there are few contacts that are having multiple Emails and multiple phone numbers.

In case of multiple phone or emails address it repeats the name of the same person multiple times.
And if i change 
`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI` 
to `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` then it will repeat name according to the number of phone number exists for a contact. Please help

```
 private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
    };

ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        final int contactIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID);
        final int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
        final int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        long contactId;

        String displayName, email, phone, photo;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            mNK_UserModel = new NK_Contact();
            contactId = cursor.getLong(contactIdIndex);
            displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);

            //Adding display name
            mNK_UserModel.setFirstName(displayName);

            Util.DEBUG_LOG(1, "contact", "contact id :" + contactId);

            al_PhoneContacts.add(mNK_UserModel);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i had to guess i would say you are missing a "break" in your while-loop. Since the cursor tries to fetch the next available column entry. But have a look at my solution which worked for me in the past.

It uses a seperate cursor for each row which gives you more control over the data.

```
                Map<String, String> contactDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contactDataMap.put(NAME, (name != null)?name:"");

                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id},
                            null);

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        contactDataMap.put(PHONE, (number != null)?number:"");
                        break;
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }

                Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String email = emailCur.getString(
                            emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                    contactDataMap.put(MAIL, (email != null)?email:"");
                    break;
                }
                emailCur.close();

                cursor.close();
```